# Android - How to load thumbnails of facebook photos?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails

I'd like to ask if there is any way to request only small-sized thumbnails of photos from facebook albums. My vision is to create an icon for every user's album that will consist from 3 overlapping photos, something like this..

[image: album icon]

..and I don't wanna wait until all large images are downloaded. Of course downloading will not run in UI thread, but still.

Answer (score 0):

It is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/picture
There are examples for several platforms/langs

Comment: Yes, but it's just one cover photo. I still can't find out how to load thumbnails of album images.

Comment: anyway... just change album to image https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/picture and set the typ you want... small, I suppose

Comment: But that's a user's photo. It seems I can't do it with album photos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/photos